# If $|G : N| = 2$ and $|S : Q| = 2$, then $Q \le N$. How prove this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S \in \mbox{Syl}_2(G)$ and $Q \le S$ such that $|S : Q| = 2$. Suppose we have some subgroup $N$ with $|G : N| = 2$ and that no element from $S \setminus Q$ is in $N$.

Then why we have $Q \le N$?

We have $N \cap S \in \mbox{Syl}_2(G)$ as $N$ is normal and by looking at the index we must have $|N \cap S| = |Q|$. Suppose $x \in Q \setminus (N \cap S)$, then $N$ is a disjoint union of $N\cap S$ and $x(N\cap S)$, also if $y \in S \setminus Q$ then $y \notin N$, hence $x(N\cap S) = y(N\cap S)$; but I am unable to get any contradiction from here...

Comment: OK, so let $R = N \cap S$. So $R,Q < S$, $|R|=|Q|=|S|/2$, and $(S \setminus Q) \cap R$ is empty. Isn't it clear that $Q=R$?

Answer (score 0):

With Derek's comment I saw this is just set theory!

For $A, B \le U$ with universe $U$, we have $A \le B \Leftrightarrow A \setminus B = \emptyset$ and $A \setminus B = A \cap (U \setminus B)$; see [wikipedia:Algebra_of_sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_algebra_of_inclusion). So with the notation as in Derek's comment:

For $R, Q \le S$ we have $R \le Q \Leftrightarrow R \setminus Q = \emptyset$ and $R \setminus Q \supseteq R \cap (S \setminus Q)$, but as $R \le S$
we also have $R \cap (S \setminus Q) \supseteq R \setminus Q$ so that $\emptyset = R \cap (S\setminus Q) = R \setminus Q$, hence $R \le Q$; and as they are both finite of equal cardinality we have $Q = R$.

But let me note that finiteness and equal cardinality is not that essential here. So suppose $R, Q \le S$ and $S$ is the disjoint union of $Q$ and $S \setminus R$ and with $(S\setminus Q) \cap R = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow Q \cup (S \setminus R) = S$ we get $R \le Q$ as above, but as the union of $Q$ and $S \setminus R$ is disjoint, the union of $R$ and $S \setminus Q$ is disjoint too and $S = Q \cup S \setminus R = R \cup S \setminus Q$, so that $Q \le R$. And the condition $|S| / 2 = |R| = |Q|$ together with $(S\setminus Q)\cap R = \emptyset$ implies that the union must be disjoint.